# Django Filter query - ignoring if the parameter is null

Tags: django, django-models, django-queryset

In my django APIView class, I am taking in month and year from a POST in the following way:

```
month = request_data.get("month")
year = request_data.get("year")
```

Then I am calling a query to get the data where the month == month and year == year.

```
queryset =  Expenses.objects.filter(month=month, year=year)
```

This totally works if I am posting the month and year. But I want to do the following:

If month is null, i want to get every record in the POST-ed year. At the moment if I POST month as null, then I don't get any results. I know this can be sorted by a simple if-else, but I want to know if there is any simpler way.

Answer (score 6):

Have you considered this?

```
filters = {'year': request_data.get("year")}

month = request_data.get("month")
if month:
    filters['month'] = month

queryset =  Expenses.objects.filter(**filters)
```

Comment: nifty little trick.Thanks man!